# Drag and drop onto Flex AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop, advanceddatagrid

How do I determine which Flex AdvancedDataGrid cell - row and column index - I've just dropped onto? calculateDropIndex seems to give me the row, but how do I get the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is going to be a pseudo code:

```
on drop:
 get x coordinate local to that grid when dropped
 loop over visible grid columns while adding their widths
 stop when total widths is greater than x coord
```

and there should be your column.

Does that help?